# GDB Python, Matplotlib change printing of float

Tags: python, matplotlib, gdb

I try to plot some array with matplotlib in gdb.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re

class plot_array_lines(gdb.Command):
    """plot an array with matplotlib lines."""

    def __init__ (self):
        gdb.Command.__init__ (self,"plot_array_lines", gdb.COMMAND_USER)     

    def invoke (self, arg, from_tty):
        line = str(gdb.parse_and_eval(arg))
        line_parse = re.sub(r' ', '', line)
        line_parse = re.sub(r'\[[0-9]\]|{|}|=', '', line_parse)
        tab = line_parse.split(',')
        for i in range(len(tab)):
            tab[i] = float(tab[i])

        plt.plot(tab, 'k')
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.show()
plot_array_lines()

class plot_array_bars(gdb.Command):
    """plot an array with matplotlib bars."""

    def __init__ (self):
        gdb.Command.__init__ (self,"plot_array_bars", gdb.COMMAND_USER)     

    def invoke (self, arg, from_tty):
        line = str(gdb.parse_and_eval(arg))
        line_parse = re.sub(r' ', '', line)
        line_parse = re.sub(r'\[[0-9]\]|{|}|=', '', line_parse)
        tab = line_parse.split(',')
        for i in range(len(tab)):
            tab[i] = float(tab[i])

        N = len(tab)
        x = range(N)
        plt.bar(x, tab, color="black")
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.show()

plot_array_bars()
```

I try to plot this array :

```
float tab2[] = {1.5,33.2,65.2,43.2,10.2,32.5,85.6,98.2,87.2,67.3};
```

The first time all is allright but the second time it fail !
The call to plt.bar change something in gdb printing.

Before the call :

```
>>> print tab2
$1 = {[0] = 1.5, [1] = 33.2000008, [2] = 65.1999969, [3] = 43.2000008, [4] = 10.1999998, [5] = 32.5, [6] = 85.5999985, [7] = 98.1999969, [8] = 87.1999969, [9] = 67.3000031}
```

After the call :

```
>>> print tab2
$2 = {[0] = 1,5, [1] = 33,2000008, [2] = 65,1999969, [3] = 43,2000008, [4] = 10,1999998, [5] = 32,5, [6] = 85,5999985, [7] = 98,1999969, [8] = 87,1999969, [9] = 67,3000031}
```

Now floating point values are displayed with a ',' instead of a '.' so my parsing failed.

Thanks fou for your help,

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the float separator character. Perhaps your computer has with some "europe" regional settings, which would lead to the software correctly interpreting the incoming numbers as float, but internally changing the output character.

Comment: The some of the underlying gui toolkits set the locale which as @Luis points out may use your local locale